# What are some good references for the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm?

Tags: references, markov-chain-montecarlo

I need to study the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm and its properties, like convergence criteria. What is a good book, paper, or website that explains it using simple terms, but without being trivial?

Answer (score 14):

An excellent introductory paper is

[Chib, Siddhartha, and Edward Greenberg. “Understanding the Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm.” *The American Statistician*, vol. 49, no. 4, 1995, pp. 327–335.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2684568)

[Free download](https://biostat.jhsph.edu/%7Emmccall/articles/chib_1995.pdf)

A masterful and concise discussion of the theory is

[Tierney, Luke. “Markov Chains for Exploring Posterior Distributions.” *The Annals of Statistics*, vol. 22, no. 4, 1994, pp. 1701–1728.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2242477)

[Free download](http://stat.rutgers.edu/home/rongchen/papers/tierney.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot. My principal target is to learn about convergence criteria, but i know only the base of Metropolis Hastings, thus all it's useful.

Comment: Start studying convergence with Tierney. An exhaustive treatment is found in Meyn and Tweedie http://probability.ca/MT/

Comment: And what about simulated annealing with Metropolis Hastings? I have read [this](http://www2.samford.edu/~sfdonald/Courses/cosc407/Papers/Introduction%20to%20simulated%20annealing%20%28Albright%29.pdf) but what about the integration with Metropolis Hastings?

Comment: Robert and Casella's book discusses simulated annealing. http://www.amazon.com/Monte-Statistical-Methods-Springer-Statistics/dp/0387212396

Comment: "Understanding..." link is broken.

Comment: (+1) highly recommend the "Understanding the Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm" paper.

Answer (score 6):

For a book that is not "heavy on the math", I'd recommend:

- [Doing Bayesian Data Analysis: A Tutorial with R and BUGS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123814855) by John K. Kruschke.

Go to Chapter 7.

R code is provided in the book, so you'll be able to play around with the examples and see, hands-on, the effects of changing the number of burn-ins and so on.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very good paper by Christian Robert describing M-H algorithm in detail

Robert, C. P. (2015). [The Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.01896) arXiv preprint arXiv:1504.01896.

and great book about Monte Carlo methods in general from the same author

Robert, C., & Casella, G. (2013). *Monte Carlo statistical methods.* Springer Science & Business Media.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to convergence criteria most work is on convergence is the Total Variation (TV) distance sense. Mostly because there is a lot of probability theory worked out for TV distance. There is a nice [survey paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1219339116) and also on the theoretical side there is the [paper by Roberts and Rosenthal](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ps/1099928648) that gives several theorems on convergence criteria. On the more practical side there are several papers written by [Jim Hobert](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~jhobert/) that provide examples of applying one of the theorems in Roberts and Rosenthal to MCMC. In general the tricky part of applying that theorem seems to be coming up with a good Lyapunov drift function.